# Moving to a WebView HTML anchor

Tags: android, html, webview, anchor

I have a help activity within my app which is simply a WebView which loads an HTML file containing all help information.

The HTML file contains a series of anchors which I would like to navigate to depending on the activity started i.e. if the user selects the help option from activity B, the help activity starts and automatically jumps to the relevant specified anchor.

My WebView code is below, is there a command I can invoke with this WebView that will jump to a specified anchor e.g. WebView.gotoAnchor(anAnchor)?

WebView code:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_help/help_main.html");
    setContentView(webView);
```

Comment: webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_help/help_main.html#Anchor"); doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly what I was after, I searched  the forum and could not find that simple line of code. Many thanks!

Comment: I added it as an answer. Please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_help/help_main.html#Anchor");
```

Answer (score 0):

like the other answer, if you load the html from the assets:

```
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_help/help_main.html#anchor");
```

but you can use it with an url.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://myurl#anchor");
```